# My phone looses the network signal while connected to ADB

Tags: android, adb

My phone start loosing network signal (only emergency calls) while is connected to ABD using USB cable. As soon i disconnect it from USB, it regains the signal.

I've tried to change the USB cable, but the same.

Does anyone experienced this weird thing?

Comment: Is that an airplane mode?

Comment: @ManojPerumarath no.

Comment: Did you try changing the modes/ File transfer,photo/charging only/ debugging on/off, please add that conditions too in the question

Comment: Did you try another USB port or PC? Probably some noise from power supply.

Comment: @lojza's conjecture is most likely to be the case. Experiment with another usb port or pc and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In  the settings of your phone did you activate the Developer options. You can choose what your phone should do when you connectit it. Is possible that you activate pictures exchange
or something like that?

here: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options

Also try another USB cable and another port.